# Flask sessions are not showing up / not respecting timeout length

Tags: session, flask

I have a flask app, trying to add SSO w/ python-saml library. I need to save authentication state across requests. I'm trying to store the auth value in session, but running into some issues. Here's the condensed code below:

views.py

```
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
...
some view class
def dispatch_request(self,**query):
        ... if some condition ...
                session['is_auth'] = auth.is_authenticated()
                app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=10)
                session.modified = True
                session.permanent = True
                session.session_cookie_secure = True
                print "session: %s" % session
```

In the logs, it shows the updated session, including the is_auth key and its value. However, I don't see this in Chrome. Here's what I see in Chrome:
https://imgur.com/zyxoAPV

The session is not timing out after 10 seconds. I have made sure to stop any background Chrome processes. I'm stumped.

Comment: What do you see in Chrome? Please edit the question.

Comment: Apologies, the question's been updated.

Comment: Set `session.permanent = True` first and then set the lifetime will make it work?